# What is the origin of 抠门儿?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I understand that 抠门儿 is an informal phrase meaning dingy. But can't figure out how these three Chinese words combined together could be used to describe a person being dingy (extremely reluctant to spend money). I googled and baidu but in vain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean stingy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://www.baike.com/wiki/抠门](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E6%8A%A0%E9%97%A8) tells:

抠门 - 历史渊源

1.古时候有一个财主，爱财如命.去寺里烧香看见庙门上的刷的金粉，他都要抠去带走。所以就有了抠门这个词语。

2.“抠门”的意思是说，吝啬到连个门把手都舍不得装，开门的时候不得不用手去抠门缝。抠门就诞生了。所以大家把吝啬的人说成是抠门。